# Cannot resolve the errors with returning an array using pointer from a function in C?

Tags: c, function, visual-c++, return-type

I am trying to receive a number of float variables through a function and then pass them to the main and store them in another array in the main. The size of the array is specified by the user, so I am using a variable-length array.
I have already searched and read similar questions about returning arrays from functions, but couldn't find a solution for the errors in my code.

For your convenience, I have summarized the original code and included only the lines related to this problem.

```c
float *receiveFloatValues(int numOfValues);

int main(void)
{
    int numberOfValues;
    float *receivedValues;

    printf("\nHow many values? ");
    scanf("%d", &numberOfValues);

    receivedValues = receiveFloatValues(numberOfValues);

    float valuesArray[numberOfValues];

    for (int counter = 0; counter < numberOfValues; counter++)
    {
        receivedValues += counter;
        valuesArray[counter] = *receivedValues;
    }

    for (int counter = 0; counter < numberOfValues; counter++)
    {
        printf("\nvaluesArray[%d]: %.2f", counter, valuesArray[counter]);
    }
    return(0);
}

float *receiveFloatValues(int numOfValues)
{
    static float values[numOfValues];
    for (int counter = 0; counter < numOfValues; counter++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter value %d: ", counter + 1);
        scanf("%.2f", &values[counter]);
    }
    return(values);
}
```

My expected result is to display the list of float values received from user, but I get these error messages:

C2057: expected constant expression

C2133: unknown size

C2466: Cannot allocate an array of constant size 0

Comment: why do you need `values[numOfValues]` to be `static`?

Comment: [C11 Standard - 5.1.2 Execution environments](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2) *"All objects with static storage duration shall be initialized (set to their initial values) before program startup."* (that cannot be satisfied with a VLA) See [C11 Standard - 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p3)

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso I thought I should use `static` because otherwise I would be passing the address of a local variable to the main which is not usually considered proper.

Comment: Omid my answer should work for you, as @DavidC.Rankin mentioned, you can't have a `static` VLA.

Comment: Additionally [C11 Standard - 6.7.6.2 Array declarators(p2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p2) *"If an identifier is declared to be an object with static or thread storage duration, it shall not have a variable length array type."*

Comment: Passing the address of a local variable is *never* proper, not just usually

Comment: *returning* that is

Comment: @Omid if you really want to do this with a VLA, you could create the array in main, and pass it in to the function. Of course, based on your comments, I'm not sure how well your compiler even supports VLAs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a `static` VLA, just use `malloc` and `free`, as shown here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float *receiveFloatValues(int numOfValues);

int main(void)
{
    int numberOfValues;
    float *receivedValues;

    printf("\nHow many values? ");
    scanf("%d", &numberOfValues);

    receivedValues = receiveFloatValues(numberOfValues);

    float *valuesArray = malloc(sizeof(float) * numberOfValues);

    for (int counter = 0; counter < numberOfValues; counter++)
    {
        valuesArray[counter] = receivedValues[counter];
    }

    for (int counter = 0; counter < numberOfValues; counter++)
    {
        printf("\nvaluesArray[%d]: %f", counter, valuesArray[counter]);
    }
    free(receivedValues);    // free memory here.
    free(valuesArray);
    return(0);
}

float *receiveFloatValues(int numOfValues)
{
    float *values = malloc(sizeof(float) * numOfValues);   // allocate memory here.
    for (int counter = 0; counter < numOfValues; counter++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter value %d: ", counter + 1);
        scanf("%f", &values[counter]);
    }
    return(values);
}
```

Comment: This code still does not compile and gives these errors: C2057: expected constant expressio, C2133: 'valuesArray' : unknown size, C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0

Comment: I literally just compiled it on my machine

Comment: @Omid You have a substandard C compiler (MSVC) which does not support variable-length arrays. You need to use malloc in main too

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks but I have no idea how to use `malloc` yet. Need to learn first and it seems very complicated to me.

Comment: @Omid you can't really do this without malloc especially if your compiler doesn't support VLAs properly.

Comment: Thanks for the new edit to the code. This code gives no compilation errors; however, as soon as I enter the first value and press ENTER, the code breaks!

Comment: yes, it's your format strings I'm guessing.

Comment: I used debugger to run the code step by step to find where the problem lies. This code receives only "Value 1" and does not receive any other value for the array. Then the code breaks at the first `free()` line.

Comment: that issue is totally unrelated to this question.

Comment: @Omid This edit fixes it though

Comment: Now it receives all the numbers but before printing them it breaks!

Comment: @Omid it works perfectly fine with my machine/compiler. And "it breaks" is not a useful error message. You should probably open a new question if you're still running into issues, this answer covers what was asked in your question